# React component does not update

Tags: jquery-ui, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dom

I am using React and Redux for my application. I have a dynamic form when i drag my question of same type my component position does not update.
For dragging i am using [JqueryUI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable)

My question object:

```
var questions : [
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title", "type" : "text"},
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title", "type" : "text"}
]
```

React Component

```
class SingleTextQuestion extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let draggableFunction = new utilityFunction();
        draggableFunction.addDraggableFeature('divQuestion_container');
    }
    render(){
        //create span or textbox based upon edit mode
        let element = Symbol();

        element = (<QuestionTitle questionNumber={this.props.questionNumber} data={this.props.data} key={this.props.key} />)


        return (
            <div id={"div_"+this.props.questionNumber} className="div_commonId" key={this.props.key}>
                <div className='icons_parent'>
                    <DragIcon />
                    <DeleteButon questionNumber={this.props.questionNumber} />
                </div>
                <div id={"q_no_title_"+this.props.questionNumber} className="q_no_title_class">
                    <QuestionNumber questionNumber={this.props.questionNumber}/>
                    <div id={"title_q"+this.props.questionNumber} className="question-title">
                        {element}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id={"typeDiv_"+this.props.questionNumber}>
                        <input id={"optionTypeElem_0_"+this.props.questionNumber}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Question Title Component

```
class QuestionTitle extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.showTextBox = this.showTextBox.bind(this)
    }
    showTextBox(content, id, type, choiceIndex){
        if(type != 'image'){
            this.props.showTextBox(content, id, type, choiceIndex);
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <span id={"title_"+this.props.questionNumber} 
            onClick={this.showTextBox.bind(this,  this.props.data.title , 
                'title_'+this.props.questionNumber, 'question_title', null)} >
                {this.props.data.title}
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

Now if i change the text of question title, the state gets updated and title is changed. And when i drag the question from 2 to 1. I update my question array  too.

```
var questions : [
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title Changed", "type" : "text"},
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title", "type" : "text"}
]
```

Question 2 remains at the same position where it was, this happend if i drag question of same type eg: text. The type of question is defined in the question object.

Comment: Uhh.. How do you render your list of questions? Do you have a component for that?

Comment: @mostruash yes i have a parent component. i fixed it by adding a random key on the selection of component to be loaded. I dont  know is it the right approach to do.

Answer (score 1):

For any list you are rendering, each list item should have a way to identify it (similar to how data is stored in databases, right?). So you can put an `id` property to each question (doesn't matter how you generate them as long as they are unique for each question). Then you can use that property as a key when rendering them using react.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `key` to the component the problem is solved.

When creating an object i appended a key to my data

```
var questions : [
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title", "type" : "text", "key_rand" : 123},
  {"name" : "Question Title", "title" : "Question Title", "type" : "text", "key_rand" : 223}
]
```

So whenever i update the array index after dragging the `key_rand` is also changed which renders the component.